# UPDATED Using grep/sed/awk as if expression to sort strings and put them to different txt files

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

Got some problem. Heres my log file.

```
otf.msn.com
otf.msn.com
accounts.google.com
Email=adresemail@gmail.com
www.x-kom.pl
login=exampleelog
allegro.pl
ssl.allegro.pl
www.bing.com
www.bing.com
www.bing.com
www.bing.com
store.steampowered.com
username=steamaccountereed
login.live.com
login=mailhotmail@hotmail.com
www.bing.com
```

I want to segregate emails, login, and sites.
to filter emails and logins from everything i'm using

```
grep -oP '\(\K[^)]*|(user=|username=|Email=|login=)[^&]*' file.txt
```

to get emails from the rest

```
grep -P '^(?=.*@.*)' file.txt
```

I was thinking about the solution to make 3 tables - emails, users 
There's my scheme

```
if "its username or mail" 
  if [email condtion]
   then write emails to emails tab
else 
write to users tab
else
 write it to 'site' table
```

What i want in output is 2 files - one with email adresses, one with users connected with sites like

```
 steampowered.com - username=steamaccountereed
    x-kom.pl - login=exampleelog
```

UPDATE : This fields (like email, username) will be used in script. 
THere will be question for user ?

```
Choose mail to send a massage:
mailhotmail@hotmail.com
adresmail@gmail.com
```

Mail adresses should be loaded from other file / table etc.

Next question for user :

```
Choose site :
steampowered.com - username=steamaccountereed
x-kom.pl - login=exampleelog
```

Moreover i need relations between users and sites : if i choose a site, i would know username from this site. The site is always 1 line above the user/login field.

I'm new in bash and need help with that ;(

Comment: Regarding the log file filtering problem: Are you asking for a regex help or is it related purely to Bash ?

Comment: Post the expected output given that sample input. Right now we can't tell if you consider `hotmail.com` a "site" because it's the domain part of an email address, nor can we tell if you consider `mailhotmail@hotmail.com` since it's a "login" and not in an `Email=` line, etc. The only `bash` part of the correct solution will be where bash calls awk and everything else will be an awk script. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn awk.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide the expected output in your question, this is just a guess but this MIGHT be what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ $0 = tolower($0) }
sub(/^(login|username)=/,"") { vals["LOGINS"][$0] }
{ sub(/^email=/,"") }
/@/  { vals["EMAILS"][$0] }
/\./ { sub(/[^@]+@/,""); vals["SITES"][$0] }
END {
    for (type in vals) {
        print type ":"
        for (val in vals[type]) {
            print "\t" val
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
SITES:
        www.bing.com
        allegro.pl
        gmail.com
        accounts.google.com
        hotmail.com
        otf.msn.com
        www.x-kom.pl
        login.live.com
        store.steampowered.com
        ssl.allegro.pl
LOGINS:
        mailhotmail@hotmail.com
        steamaccountereed
        exampleelog
EMAILS:
        adresemail@gmail.com
        mailhotmail@hotmail.com
```

The above uses GNU awk for true multi-D arrays.

Comment: IT's likely what i want. Thanks a lot. But there's a email adress in logins. 
Is there possibility to use awk '/@/'  file.txt to filter the email adresses?

Comment: Of course, it's only software and whatever it is you want to do is trivial but you've got to edit your question to **show us** what exactly you want because peeling the onion with guesswork and requirements getting added in comments is too frustrating to deal with.

Comment: I edited my answer with another (and final!) guess at what you might want.

Comment: Updated what i want. Sorry, my english is not quite good to describe this well. Hope there's enough info what i want to get :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with speaking English - simply edit your question to show the expected output given that sample input. Your edits sound like a whole new set of requirements based on what you want to do with the result of your first question, but you still haven't shown us the expected output from your first question. Focus on the original question first then ask a followup if you need to.

Comment: Ok. In output i would expect 2 txt files - one with email adresses , one with users/logins/usernames connected with sites as i show in updated example.

Comment: For the 3rd (or 4th? time) - EDIT YOUR QUESTION to show what you want and actually SHOW THE DESIRED OUTPUT given the input you posted. I'm done, hopefully someone else will be able to help you.